# Shrinking with realloc

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I encountered this small piece of code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3788696/191776), & wanted to know,

Can the `realloc()` function ever move a memory block to another location, when the memory space pointed to is shrinked?

```
int * a = malloc( 10*sizeof(int) );
int * b = realloc( a, 5*sizeof(int) );
```

If possible, under what conditions, can I expect `b` to have an address different from that in `a`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible for `realloc` to move memory on any call.  True in many implementations a shrink would just result in the change of the reserved size in the heap and wouldn't move memory.  However in a heap which optimized for low fragmentation it may choose to move the memory around to a better fitting location.

Don't depend on `realloc` keeping memory in the same place for any operation.

Comment: Just to remove any doubt, I've actually encountered this situation on iOS 6 where a realloc of 40K down to 224 bytes actually moves the memory to a new location.