# realloc behaviour while downsizing the memory held by the pointer

Tags: c, realloc

**Confusion 1**:
The `man realloc` says that the object will be moved if it has to do a new allocation to resize the object to a new size. However when downsizing, there are many places which says [*it is possible to move data in memory to a new place*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788966/shrinking-with-realloc)(SO). This is creating confusions in my head. How do we find that downsizing will rsult in new allocation or not as it is not explicitly mentioned for downsizing case in the man pages and in [*gnu page*](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Changing-Block-Size.html).

**Confusion 2**:
Also when we do following:

```
void * ptr1 = malloc(SOMEBIGSIZE);
void * ptr2 = realloc(ptr1, SOMESMALLSIZE);
```

evaluating `ptr1==ptr2` results true. Which means that the ptr2 points same ptr1. So, which of the 2.1 or 2.2 is true?
**(2.1)** that ptr1 was not downsized which can be bad if SOMEBIGSIZE>>>SOMESMALLSIZE and we do not get any advantage in terms of memory.
**(2.2)** if the ptr1 is shrinked, then what happens to the memory in address range ptr1+SOMESMALLSIZE to ptr1+SOMEHUGESIZE? is it freed or marked free?

Comment: My understanding is that `realloc` is free to move the memory block as it sees fit.

Comment: @Ed Heal: yes it seems obvious when upsized. It should also do same when downsizing have huge difference compared to initial size. but it do not. Why? thats the question is about. And if it does so, we should have documnetation about that too

Comment: @adhinav - Why? Just leaves a "hole" in the memory that can be used at a later date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard talks out the behavior of realloc from perspective of user program. It does not define the implementation.

Following are the relevant requirements(asked in your Q) imposed by the standard on Implementations.

**C99 Standard 7.20.3.4-1: The realloc function:**

> The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size speciﬁed by size. The contents of the new
>   object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. **Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have indeterminate values.**

**C99 Standard 7.20.3.4-4:**

> The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object **(which may have the same value as a pointer to the old object)**, or a null pointer if the new object could not be allocated.

Comment: should we use the term **object** while refering to C?

Comment: @abhinav: That is a quote from the c99 Standard.Do not confuse it with Object Oriented paradigm.

Comment: And yes, what you have stated is OK. but we are discussing here something that seems to be not explicitly said by manuals.

Comment: @abhinav: *seems to be not explicitly said by manuals*, I provided you a C standard quote saying the new pointer returned may or may not be same as old pointer. That is explicit enough.

Comment: downvoted, really? +1 from me than. The two paras that you cited are the only things you'd have to know.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first confusion, you really need to read the gnu page better.

> In several allocation implementations, making a block smaller sometimes necessitates copying it, so it can fail if no other space is available.

Now, for the second confusion, any of the two is possible. It depends on the particular implementation of malloc, and there's no restriction (that I know of) that requires that one particular case to always be true.

Comment: yes i have read it many times. Thats why what does this **_several_** means here. They are not mentioning something other than GNU, then the use of **_several_** and similar terms creates the confusion

Comment: Given that the Standard would allow a realloc() call to simply do nothing in cases where the requested new size isn't greater than than the actual size, in what implementations would there be any non-trivial cost to guaranteeing that a realloc() which does request that a size larger than the previous requested size will always succeed?  For the pattern "Make an allocation at least as large as needed; populate the data structure; shrink the allocation to meet requirement", can implementations receive any benefit from requiring that source code check for a failure in the shrink request?

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that the spec don't prohibit `realloc` to do nothing in that case.

But if `ptr1==ptr2` and if the system `malloc` functionality is not too dumb, I would imagine it could mark the unused memory range as reusable for future `malloc`-s, or perhaos sometimes give it back to the system (e.g. using [munmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/munmap.html) system calls on Posix).

And my (limited) understanding of the standards makes me think that an implementation which always return a null pointer for `malloc` and does nothing for `realloc` is still respecting the letter (but not the spirit) of the standards.

Comment: sire, you are again talking like the man/gnu pages. **_think_** and **_believe_** are again confusing :)

Comment: If you really want a specific answer, look at the source of your malloc implementation (and this may mean to choose a malloc implementation for the availability of its source code). On all usual systems (Windows, Linux, Unix-es, MacOSX), malloc is implemented above a lower-level memory system call (mmap & munmap on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

That's the thing. You never know when `realloc` is going to allocate another memory block and copy data because there is no API that allows you to look at "malloc" internals and see if allocated region can be extended or shrunk.

Answer (score 0):

The important lesson here is that the standard describes the *effects* of `malloc()/realloc()` not what they actually *do*. This is done to give the implementers of the standard library freedoms to make optimizations, cuts, or changes to the behavior of these function, without affecting the code that uses them. **The standard is preventing you from making assumptions about what is smart or what is happening, because it might not be.**

From the programmer's perspective, this could be the allocator(less some error checking):

```
  void*
  malloc(size_t amt){
       static char *base = NULL;
       if(base==NULL)
              base = sbrk(0);
       char *c = base+1;
       base=sbrk(amt+5);
       return c;
  }
  void*
  realloc(void *old, size_t amt){
        return memcpy(malloc(amt), old, amt);
  }
  void free(void *v){}
```

I call her `swalloc`, the Silly Wasteful Allocator.